# Find object from array of objects where key is from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I am struck getting right object for my javascript code.
I have 2 arrays.

```
var filters = [{"name":"hello","value":"xyz"},{"name":"hello2","value":"abc"}]
var keys = ["hello","hello2"]
```

I want to find object where name is "hello".
I am trying with underscore.js

```
var selectedObj = _.findWhere(filters , { name: ??? });
```

I cannot pass "hello"/key[0] directly. I have to use keys array to fill the "???".

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just `_.findWhere(filters , { name: keys[0] });`

Comment: How would you want it to work?  What would you want to pass?  This can easily be custom built.

Answer (score 0):

Use _.find instead of findWhere:

```
    var result = [];
_.each(keys, function (key) {
    _.find(filters, function (item) {
        //loop through array , check key and return object
        if (key === item.name)
            result.push(item);
    });
});
```

They are similar, but findWhere is designed for special cases where you want to match key-value pairs (not useful in your scenario as it involves nested objects).  Find is more general-use, because it lets you provide a function as the predicate.

Comment: Thanks. I was little confused to connect arrays of object and strings.